# enable pam module as default

Tags: pam

I want to enable some pam modules automatically in a script. *mkhomedir* is disabled as default. If you start **pam-auth-update**, there is no check mark in

```
Create home directory on login
```

How can I change this?

There is a configuration file

```
/usr/share/pam-configs/my_mkhomedir
```

containing

```
Name: activate mkhomedir
Default: no
Priority: 900
Session-Type: Additional
Session:
        required                        pam_mkhomedir.so umask=002 skel=/etc/skel
```

Changing the priority value changes the ordering in pam-auth-update, but *Default: yes* does not enable it as default. Is there any other option to enable this module as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I edited the `mkhomedir` config file changing `Default: no` to `Default: yes`

Then I ran this command:

```
pam-auth-update --enable mkhomedir
```

I checked the `pam-auth-update` ncurses gui afterwards and the box was now selected

Comment: Thanks, that is working! I didn't know that I have to use "--enable mkhomedir" although default is set to yes.